# Use an SDK that comes with .h .lib and .dll file

Tags: c++, dll, sdk

I would like to use an SDK for a device in my Visual Studio C++ Project.
So I am including the header file from the SDK in my `cpp` file.
Where in the project settings do I have to tell the linker about the `lib` file?
And where do I put the `lib` and `dll`?

The header file exports various functions and looks like this:

```
#ifdef FOO_EXPORTS
#define FOO_API extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define FOO_API extern "C" __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

namespace foo
{
 FOO_API long bar();
 FOO_API long bar2(int i);
}
```

Comment: Go to the project properties and set the external library dependies path to your lib path. Keep the lib and dll in the same folder...Simple google it, you will get it on msdn website.

Answer (score 2):

To use a .lib, add your lib in

```
 Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input
```

.
If you have a lot of libs in a folder, turn to

```
Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories
```

, add your folder of libs here

For dll,if you will use this sdk in many projects (such as opengl), you can just put .dll in

```
c://windows/system32
```

But usually just put it in the folder of your project

refer to 
 [Dynamic Link Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636.aspx) 

 [Static Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235627.aspx)